# How to clone production db on Heroku to development db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm on Ruby on Rails 3.2.13.

SQLite3 in local development environment.

Production environmet at Heroku (PostgreSQL).

What is the most updated (!= deprecated) and easiest way to pull the db from production to development with the above prerequisites?

Comment: You really should be using postgresql when developing locally though, not sqlite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do that with the taps gem

heroku db:pull

there are some posts about this topic at heroku as well:

https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: In their very recent documentation (your second link), they mention PG Backups. Is that a replacement for the taps gem, and the use case similar?

Comment: i don't think so. AFAIK it creates Postgres backups. That would not be very handy for your sqlite3 db.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull your latest production env from Heroku with a command like this:

```
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

From there you will want to convert the dump from PG to something that SQLite can read. The steps for that are:

1. Remove the lines starting with `SET`
2. Remove the lines starting with `SELECT pg_catalog.setval`
3. Replace `true` for `‘t’`
4. Replace `false` for `‘f’`
5. Add `BEGIN;` as first line and `END;` as last line

Lastly, you need to import that into SQLite.

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
sqlite> delete from schema_migrations;
sqlite> .read latest.sql
```

You can read [details on this procedure here](http://manuel.manuelles.nl/blog/2012/01/18/convert-postgresql-to-sqlite/).